# Converting LAS data from buildings to detailed shapes using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: shapefile, lidar, las, multipatch, arcgis-pro

What we want to achieve is to convert LAS data to a GIS format like shapes. On the internet, there are enough examples how to convert the LAS data height to a building footprint.

What we want is extra detail, the basic shape of the footprint should be split where the building changes in height.

How do we convert LAS data to a footprint shape where (with the right settings) it splits a shape into more shapes with height like this?

Example of what to achieve:

[image]

It would be nice if the multipatch feature would allow this, but so far we didn't find an answer in that direction.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195417/generating-surfaces-of-different-heights-from-lidar-points (software agnostic).

Answer (score 3):

For conversion I use [LASTools](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/).  A simple `las2shp` will solve your conversion issue.

Now for your main issue, you can try [Split by Attributes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm). In your case I have some ideas on how to use `Split by Attributes`, so I'll try to explain:

1. After conversion you can take the Z value, "cut off" the decimals
   and use Split to isolate areas with the same height. Convert to
   raster and the raster to polygon the get your building's footprint.
2. After conversion to SHP, do a `Topo to Raster`, convert raster to a integer (you'll have to play with the decimals again here), then
   `Raster to Polygon`, then `Split by Attributes`.
3. Try this: [Generating surfaces of different heights from LIDAR points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195417/generating-surfaces-of-different-heights-from-lidar-points)
   if you have not already.

Let us know if any of this work for you or you found another solution. I am really curious about this subject.